# Entity Framework web or Entity Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have got a assignment question from my college, there is a line as follows

> This must be implemented using C# and utilize the **Entity Framework classes**.

this means Entity Objects or Entity Framework??
and can I implement Entity Framework as a C# desktop application

please help me to understand this. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use Entity framework for desktop application. Create one project as desktop application and add another as the business logic project, this should be one that uses entity framework objects to communicate with your database. Lastly, another project that will implement all your desired methods in relation to the entity framework project. This is the project that the windows application communicate with directly. Check out here for [some tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B)

You can combine it as one project but I prefer separation of concern so you can compile the business logic as a dll. Entity framework is just one of the object relation mapping model and it can be used across various projects types. Others include NHibernate, LINQ to SQL etc

Comment: thanks lot... you explain is fantastic... good luck for your future, +1

Answer (score -1):

it is a library that can be used either on web or desktop .NET project: [You can get it here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.0.2)